# how to create a UITableViewCell with an "info symbol" in the accessoryView/disclosure area? (like the iTunes Connect app)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, app-store-connect

What's the best way to create a `UITableViewCell` with an "info symbol" in the accessoryView/disclosure area?   Like the `iTunes Connect app`, that is when you login there is teh `Account Name` cell, which has an "info" button you can click on.  It basically has the text `Account Name` on the left, then a text field for entry of the account name, and on the right the info icon you can click on.

Aspects of the question:
- which `UITableViewCell` style is it using?
- is there a way to set the `info` button as a disclosure type?  or is it a custom cell where you have to put your own image there
- then depending on the answer to the above item, how would you trap the info button button push to trigger some help text to be displayed as a modal dialog

Background - I wanted to use this as a means to allow users to get context based help on each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this set the frame according to where u want

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
button.frame = CGRectMake(3,8,30, 30);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Or just set info button as accessory view: `cell.accessoryView = button;`

Comment: thanks - I tried the "cell.accessoryView = button" approach.  I noted however when I did click within the UITextField which is a contentView subview, that there is a shadow/offset info image in the accessoryview area...any idea?

Comment: here's an example of the shadow I'm seeing - again everything looks good until I click on the textField, and then the shadow appears: http://postimage.org/image/32nafruxw/

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is 
You can just set a detail accessory view:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureIndicator;
```

This gives a little arrow > on the right. When the user taps a cell, the tableView delegate gets a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message. With a disclosure indicator, you generally respond by pushing a new viewController containing the desired information.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.itemHelpVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks Suz - but I actually wanted the info/help icon (like on the iTunes Connect app) - Ron/Nikto's answer is 99% of the way there, but I'm just getting a shadow/offset info image in the accessoryView after I click on the textField which is the contentView area of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8 the UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton has the form of an info button, so you just need this:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
```

Result:

[image: tableviewcell with accessory detail button]